# Factoring $p(x)=16x^4-16x^3-4x^2+4x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to prove that the Decagon is constructible by straightedge and compass. I've already found another way to do it (involving a $2nd$ degree polynomial instead of a $5th$ degree polynomial) but I'm still curious about factoring the following.

On my approach, I reached the polynomial $p(x)=16x^5-20x^3+5x+1$, and it's easy to see that,
$$p(x)=16x^5-20x^3+5x+1=(x+1)(16x^4-16x^3-4x^2+4x+1)$$

and I get stuck there. If you have any hint to approach this problem or a more general case it would be awesome.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(4x^2 - 2x - 1)^2$

Comment: Note that factorisation in general is a highly nontrivial problem. I found this by inputting `(16*x^4-16*x^3-4*x^2+4*x+1).factor()` to this webpage https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ and press "Evaluate".

Comment: Oh, yes! Of course I can put it on https://www.wolframalpha.com and see that haha, but I don't know how to reach that point. Do you know how to do it? Do you have a hint or strategy for a more general case?

Comment: This is a very large topic. In your case, one strategy is to try factorising it as $(4x^2 + ax + 1)(4x^2 + bx + 1)$ or $(4x^2 + ax - 1)(4x^2 + bx - 1)$ or $(2x^2 + ax + 1)(8x^2 + bx + 1)$ etc.

Comment: I searched and found [a lot of similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=16x%5E4-16x%5E3-4x%5E2%2B4x%2B1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing worth doing is searching for repeated factors, by finding the GCD of the original polynomial and its derivative. Sometimes you get rational coefficients and need to think about it, but this time the algorithm spits out your $ \left(  4 x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right) $

$$  \left(  16 x^{5}  - 20 x^{3}  + 5 x  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  16 x^{4}  - 12 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  16 x^{5}  - 20 x^{3}  + 5 x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(  16 x^{4}  - 12 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) } +  \left(   - 8 x^{3}  + 4 x  + 1 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  16 x^{4}  - 12 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   - 8 x^{3}  + 4 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   - 2 x  \right) } +  \left(   - 4 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   - 8 x^{3}  + 4 x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   - 4 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   - 2 x  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   - 2 x^{2}  + 1 \right) }{ \left(   - 2 x  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   - 4 x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 3 x  + 1 \right) }{ \left(   - 4 x^{2}  - 2 x  + 1 \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(  4 x^{3}  + 2 x^{2}  - 3 x  - 1 \right)  \left(   - 2 x  \right)  -  \left(  4 x^{2}  + 2 x  - 1 \right)  \left(   - 2 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  16 x^{5}  - 20 x^{3}  + 5 x  + 1 \right)  =  \left(  4 x^{3}  + 2 x^{2}  - 3 x  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(  4 x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  16 x^{4}  - 12 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(  4 x^{2}  + 2 x  - 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(  4 x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(  4 x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(  16 x^{5}  - 20 x^{3}  + 5 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   - 2 x  \right)  -  \left(  16 x^{4}  - 12 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left(   - 2 x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(  4 x^{2}  - 2 x  - 1 \right)  $$